Events are not being broadcasted as expected
My event broadcast is not working and I can't find out why.
Providing all relevant files and config here.

Processes running:

php artisan websockets:serve
php artisan queue:work


My .env relevant entries for pusher are:

QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
PUSHER_APP_ID=testapp
PUSHER_APP_KEY=websocketkey
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=somethingsecret
PUSHER_HOST=127.0.0.1
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"


This is my config.broadcasting.connections:

'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'useTLS' => true,
                // 'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http'
            ],
        ],
//...


This is my config.websockets:

'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'host' => env('PUSHER_APP_HOST'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => true,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
            'allowed_origins' => [
                // env('LARAVEL_WEBSOCKETS_DOMAIN'),
            ],
        ],
    ],
//...


resources/bootstrap.js:

//...
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true
});


This is the controller method I'm using to fire the event:

  public function handle(Request $request)
  {
    $message = $request->all();
    Log::info('Twilio request received: ', $message);

    $sid = config("services.twilio.sid");
    $token = config("services.twilio.token");
    $twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

    $chatMessage = new ChatMessage([
      'from' => $message['From'],
      'to' => $message['To'],
      'body' => $message['Body'],
      'direction' => 'inbound',
      'sid' => $message['SmsMessageSid'],
      'messagingServiceSid' => $message['MessagingServiceSid'],
      'status' => $message['SmsStatus'],
      'numMedia' => $message['NumMedia'],
      'dateSent' => now()->tz('UTC'),
    ]);

    $chatMessage = ChatMessage::storeMessages([$chatMessage], $twilio)->first();
    ChatMessageReceived::dispatch($chatMessage);
  }


ChatMessageReceived event:

class ChatMessageReceived implements ShouldBroadcast
{
  use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

  public $chatMessage;

  public function __construct(ChatMessage $chatMessage)
  {
    $this->chatMessage = $chatMessage;
  }

  public function broadcastOn()
  {
    $roomId = $this->chatMessage->chat_room_id;
    Log::info('ChatMessageRecived: ', ['roomId' => $roomId]); //This is logging as expected
    return new PrivateChannel('rooms.'. $roomId);
  }
}


This is the method used in the vue component to listen for messages:

  methods: {
    listenMessages(room) {
        console.log('Listening messages for room: ', room);
        const listener = Echo.private(`rooms.${room.roomId}`).listen('ChatMessageReceived', (e) => {
          console.log('ChatMessageReceived listener: ', e); //This log is never logged!
        });
        this.listeners.push(listener);
  }
  //...

Could you guys please help me determine the cause of this issue?
I'm for hours in this without success.
